# bigquery geojson concat multiple rows from same user to a single row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gis, apache-superset

How do I merge multiple rows from the same user into a single geojson formatted row, I tried order by with no luck. here is a sample code I am using, I am also limited to select only on this db

```
SELECT rh.routeid, st_asgeojson(st_geogpoint(locs.lon, locs.lat)   
FROM demo.routebatches RB, demo.route R
cross join UNNEST(locations) as locs
where EXTRACT (date FROM TIMESTAMP_MILLIS (CAST(locs.date as INT64))) =  "2017-03-10" and rh.cycleID = 'aff9bb7b-3b92-4620-bc50-1152edefe04c'
order by routeID
limit 100
```

which gives this result, where multiple long and lats from the same routeid are not ordered by routeid. How do I solve this?

Geojson would work but I would also take this format, which is from deck.gl path in superset

[image: superset deck.gl path]

[image: bigquery reult]

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1. how to order the locations within route. You write `where multiple long and lats from the same routeid are not ordered by routeid` - but this is a confusing statement. All these points (`same routeid`) have identical routeid, so how can they be ordered `by routeid`? You probably want them to order within the routeid group, but you need a different field to order them by.
2. you need to combine all the points within the routeid into a linestring, instead of having each point separate.

Also, it is not clear what is the actual input schema, and how routebatches table relates to route table, it would help if you clarify. Does `locations` field belong to RB or R table? The way you join RB and R tables without any predicate makes a cross join of each RB row with each R row.

It looks like `locations` record has a `date` field in milliseconds - if we can order by this field, I would use something like

```
SELECT 
  rh.routeid, 
  st_asgeojson(st_makeline(
    array_agg(st_geogpoint(locs.lon, locs.lat) order by locs.date)))
FROM demo.route R cross join UNNEST(locations) as locs
where 
  EXTRACT (date FROM TIMESTAMP_MILLIS (CAST(locs.date as INT64))) =  "2017-03-10" 
  and rh.cycleID = 'aff9bb7b-3b92-4620-bc50-1152edefe04c'
GROUP BY routeID
order by routeID
limit 100
```

First, we GROUP BY routeId, we then aggregate (`array_agg`) all the points in this route, creating an array with all the points ordered by the timestamp. `st_makeline` builds a linestring from this array, which you can then convert to geojson.

Also, see this article that creates a similar linestring from public NOAA data:
https://mentin.medium.com/longest-hurricane-eeb6844d65ed

Comment: Thanks for your help, that did the trick. Maybe you can can also help with this as well, how do i remove the double quotes from this?  json_extract_array(st_asgeojson(st_makeline(
    array_agg(st_geogpoint(locs.lon, locs.lat) order by locs.date))),'$.coordinates') as geo   which gives this result ["[-8.6359,40.6371716666667]", "[-8.63589166666667,40.637165]", "[-8.63589333333333,40.6371583333333]", "[-8.63589,40.637165]", "[-8.63588833333333,40.6371716666667]"]